# IntelliJ, Grails - I deleted a file and nothing works anymore

Tags: grails, ide, groovy, intellij-idea

I need help with IntelliJ, my project isnt starting anymore, I googled but cant find a solution. It started when I deleted a newly created file, a grails Service file. 
First, the grails view disappeared. Adding new Framework Support to the project and get the view back via tool windows didnt work.
I also have no "grails" option in the tool menu anymore.
When I run the project (I had to re-setup the run configuration, it was all sort-of-deleted too), the console shows me this error:
Application expects grails version [1.2.3], but GRAILS_HOME is version [1.3.7].
All my Team memebers use 1.3.7 too, so I dont know why this should work.

Can somebody help me please.
Please let me know if you require more information to help me!

thanks a lot in advance!
daniel

Comment: how much modules can you see in the project view? there must be one for your grails application named <app name> and one for your grails plugins <app name>-grailsPlugins. maybe you accidentally deleted one of those intellj modules. you can also control whether all configuration files exist.

Comment: hmm, I just have one module - Grailsweb(in projectname-grailsPlugins). This could be it! How do I get the other one back?

Comment: I'm guessing you somehow deleted the .idea directory, in which case you'd have to completely set up your project again. Are you using some sort of version control? Then you could rollback to the last working version.

Comment: the modules files located under your project root and named as follows: <app name>.iml. in intellij go to file -> project structure -> modules. there you can add a existing module by clicking the + symbol and select your existing module for importing

Comment: yes I do use it :) I set up a new project, a dozen times. It either doesnt get the files from subversion, or, if I first get the files from subversion, and then create a new project out of it, it doesnt show the 'grails view', wich is very useful (I add framework support in the new project again). So I know now my project is fubar, but does anyone know maybe why the new project doesnt work either?. Thank you guys so far!

Comment: Im gonna try hitty5 advice now, thanks!

Comment: @hitty5 you just saved me a lot of time and nerves.After adding the .iml, tt all works again. Id give you 1000 reputation for this if I could, thanks to all of you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how much modules can you see in the project view? there must be one for your grails application named  and one for your grails plugins -grailsPlugins. maybe you accidentally deleted one of those intellj modules. the modules files are located under your project root and named as follows: .iml. in intellij go to file -> project structure -> modules. there you can add a existing module by clicking the + symbol and select your existing module for importing.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was compiled at least once then I guess one can open the .class file with intellij and see the code. However all coments will be remove of course.